# Can I add more functionality to a class in python?

Tags: python, class

If one has a partial `class` definition like this...

```
class Atom(object):
    def _init_(self, id, mass = 0, pos = None, radius = 0):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.mass = 0
```

Could one add the `self.name` part and still have it represent the `class`?

Comment: Are you wanting the name of the class, `Atom`?

Comment: Above code has some serious syntax errors. And what do you mean by `represent the class`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand the question. Could you please be clearer? :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your class to have the variable, `name`, you have to pass it in with the other arguments.

```
class Atom(object):
    def _init_(self, id=None, name=None, mass=0, pos=None, radius=0):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        ...
```

Then you can access/assign it inside your class. Otherwise if you are just trying to get the name of the class it can be done without the need of assigning it, like so:

```
a = Atom()
a.__class__.__name__
>>> 'Atom'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since python classes provide all the standard features of Object Oriented Programming: the class inheritance mechanism allows multiple base classes, a derived class can override any methods of its base class or classes, and a method can call the method of a base class with the same name :

Yes you can add more functionality to a class in python.